# Swift 4: Dismiss closure code not executing

Tags: ios, swift

First let me say ive tried just about everything out there to fix this problem and I cant for the life of me figure it out.

The code:

```
 self.messagesControl?.showChatController()
```

is not running , it is inside a dismiss() closure why is that the print line following this runs , and not the line of code above? please help!

messagesControl method call

```
 var messagesControl : MessagesViewController?
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
            self.messagesControl?.showChatController()
            print("dismiss closure finished running")
        })

}
```

showChatController()

```
 func showChatController()
{
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToChatLogControllerPlz", sender: self)
}
```

**Expected Result:**
segue is run print line executes

**Observed Result:**

print line executes. no segue :(

**EDIT**

i have replaced :

```
self.messagesControl?.showChatController()
```

With:

```
      self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showChatController", sender: self)
```

Still getting same result tho :(

Comment: How have you assigned messagesControl? Are you sure, messagesControl is not nil when you call it inside completionHandler of dismiss.

Comment: Im sure that is not the problem as I have directly linked up a segue to test and got the same issue, i am using this tutorial ( ima noob )

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cw0gLZHJOiE&list=PL0dzCUj1L5JEfHqwjBV0XFb9qx9cGXwkq&index=9

Comment: @ZackJensen117 I don't understand your segues connection. What's the `MessagesViewController` itself. Can you explain it?

Comment: @Mannopson messagesViewController is a view that holds all your conversations like in iMessage, i used the segue i already had in there which brought you to a specific conversation. check the youtube video above to see the tutorial i'm using as i am a noob. Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: You are calling segue on the dismissed view controller. There might be no need to dismiss it(if I understand the case). You are going from master view to the detail. If so just call the segue without dismissing previous.

Comment: Problem is that you view controller doesn't exist in the memory after calling dismiss. So, you can do this by using custom delegate from https://useyourloaf.com/blog/quick-guide-to-swift-delegates/

Answer (score 0):

The way apple does dismiss is wierd.  You can call it on the presented VC or on the presenter.  Which are you doing here?  If you are calling it on the presented view controller then it leaves memory after dismiss, and in any case it shouldn't be showing the next view controller; the parent should.

There are three ways you can deal with this:

1. Use an unwind segue.  When the parent gets the unwind it will call
   dismiss and perform the segue in the compeletion handler as you have
   it now.
2. Use a delegate and tell the parent when the modal showu;d be dismissed.  the parent then calls dismiss and initiates the segue.
3. Before dismiss reach up the UIResponder chain to find your parent VC.  In the completetion for dismiss call performSegue on your parent VC.

Method 1 is preferred if only the final state of the modal is relavant (ie you don't need a delegate for anything else).  Method 2 is preferred if you are already using a delegate for something else.  Method 3 is the least code but is generally poor style unless your parent VC conforms to some standard protocol that you can invoke.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UINavigationController.popViewController(:).

In your closure add:

```
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

It will apply the reverse animation when VC is dismissed.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you're trying to perform a segue from a `View Controller` that does not exist anymore. What you should do is connect the segue to the parent of the view controller in question and have the parent view controller perform the segue. Your code will look something like this

```
var messagesControl : MessagesViewController?
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: { [weak self]
        self?.parent?.showChatController()
    })
}
```

In the parent view controller

```
func showChatController(){
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToChatLogControllerPlz", sender: self)
}
```